# Checking if object is null throws an exception?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

When executing a foreach searching for null values it throws an exception instead of executing the code specified for null-objects.

```
foreach (Requirement requirement in DBRequirements)
{
    if (this.Repository.GetElementByGuid(requirement.Guid) == null)
    {
        hasChanges = true;
        requirement.IsDeleted = true;
    }
}
```

`Repository.GetElementByGuid()` is a function from Enterprise Architect. I can't modify this and thus I'll have to assume when not found it immediately throws an exception instead of returning `null`? (Haven't been able to find out for sure, documentation is kind of scarce on this.) I'm thinking about using a `try catch` as `if else` but I'm wondering if anyone has a better suggestion.

Basically what's supposed to happen; it checks every requirement in the DB if it's Enterprise Architect-counterpart still exists. If it doesn't, the DB should mark the current requirement as `IsDeleted`, if it does nothing needs to be done. It's part of a synchronization cycle to update the DB. 
Guid is a unique identifier within Enterprise Architect.

**Edit:** Forgot to actually mention the exception.. It's throwing the exception on the if-statement as a:

> NullReferenceException

...on `GetElementByGuid(requirement.Guid)`, stating that no such element exists in the current context.

For clarification;

DBRequirements is pulled straight from the database and checked if not empty, requirement.Guid can't be null because it's the primary-key in the database (and thus NOT NULL), the data-base record could simply not exist without it. This.Repository is declared in the constructor (checked with debugger in runtime, it's also not `null`).

This is why I'm unable to find out what is throwing the exception. Something returns to be `null`, but nothing is within this foreach actually does have a `null` -value.

Comment: what is the exception, is it null reference exception  ?

Comment: Maybe `this.Repository == null`?

Comment: or `requirement` could be null. We need the exception and some context

Comment: Sorry, forgot to actually mention the exception, edit on main post

Comment: @MickyD Repository is declared in constructor so can't be null either (and is not null, checked with debugger)

Comment: @Ciphra My best bet is: one of the internals of Repostiory is null (or has become null). StackTrace in the exception usually shows where the exception comes from!

Comment: There's a difference between older versions and newer in the way the operation `Repository.GetElementByGUID` behaves. It used to throw an Exception if the element was not found, but recently (version 12 IIRC) it returns null. Anyway, put the piece of code in a try-catch block to make sure.

Comment: @Chipra Yes it wont throws exception now as Geert mentioned. Here your condition seems to be wrong .Change it to not equal to null (!=) from (==) .Hope your exceptions is thrown from requirement.Isdeleted line because as your condition even if requirement is not found youre trying to et that bool value.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I'll put it in a try-catch to use as a work-around for now, I'll keep looking for a more clear and 'acceptable' solution.

Comment: @dahsra that would do the opposite of what I'm trying to do :^). That'd make it so that if the requirement I have in the database DOES exist in EA it will remove it from the DB.

Answer (score 3):

try this where you only use `DBRequirements` that have `Guids`

```
foreach (Requirement requirement in DBRequirements.Where(r => r?.Guid != null))
{
    if (this.Repository.GetElementByGuid(requirement.Guid) == null)
    {
        hasChanges = true;
        requirement.IsDeleted = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Guid can't be null in the database as it's the primary key.

Comment: This also protects the case if the `requirement` is null

Comment: afaik, but I could be wrong in understanding this, it's not possible for any of the `requirement`s in `DBRequirements` to be `null`, as they are pulled straight from the DB (in the DB a record can't be `null`, it MUST have at least the `Guid`) and it's treated (not set) as a `readonly` and thus never modified from there on.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code..

```
foreach (Requirement requirement in DBRequirements)
{
    if (requirement != null)
    {
        if (this.Repository.GetElementByGuid(requirement.Guid) == null)
        {
            hasChanges = true;
            requirement.IsDeleted = true;
        }
    }
}
```